# I'm having trouble making a recursive function for phone number-letter mapping

Tags: python

so basically I'm creating a function that takes in a multiple digits and returns a list of the possible words(they can be real or fake) that the phone number spells (its called phone number letter mapping)

so this is what I did

Step 1: I convert the string of numbers into a list of possible letters corresponding to each number in the string.

this is basically trying to get the rows corresponding to each index of the list !

> 0 –> []  1 –> []  2 –> [A,B,C]  3 –> [D,E,F]  4 –> [G,H,I]  5 –>
> [J,K,L]  6 –> [M,N,O]  7 –> [P,Q,R,S]  8 –> [T,U,V]  9 –> [W,X,Y,Z]

step 2: I tried to recursively collect the multiple letter combinations in a string but kinda failed miserably

for example
m = "2629327"
compare(m, m[1:], 0, 0, 0) => AM AA AW AD AA AP etc etc
when the expected result is COBWEBS BOAWEBS COAXEAR ANAXEAR etc

It would be much easier to use nested for loops, but I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish this with recursion only

Comment: How does a 4-digit number produce 6-letter words? Or waht is the example in the end: "2160" -> "COBWEBS", ...

Comment: so sorry i made a mistake

Comment: I don't understand the point of the two lists and three positions.

Comment: Ah cause i was trying to add the first row with the rest of row (the two lists are virtually identical)

Comment: You are overcomplicating this. Take one list-of-lists parameter `L`, then for every letter of the first element of `L`: add it to the front of all results you get from recursing on `L[1:]`. Stop when `L` is empty. Done.

Comment: so something like L[0][pos] + funtion(L[1:], pos +1).... ?

Comment: No, no `pos`. Leave indices and positions out of it and focus on structure. (I suspect that you're thinking in terms of loops. Don't.)

Answer (score 1):

Your function seems overly complicated. A simple recursive solution:

```
mapping = [[''],
           [''], # empty string makes for for simpler code
           ['A', 'B', 'C'],
           ['D', 'E', 'F'],
           ['G', 'H', 'I'],
           ['J', 'K', 'L'],
           ['M', 'N', 'O'],
           ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S'],
           ['T', 'U', 'V'],
           ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']]

def num2word(s):
    if not s:
        yield ""
        return
    first, rest = s[0], s[1:]
    for char in mapping[int(first)]:
        for word in num2word(rest):
            yield char + word

list(num2word("2160"))
# ['AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'BM', 'BN', 'BO', 'CM', 'CN', 'CO']
list(num2word("2629327"))
# ['AMAWDAP', 'AMAWDAQ', 'AMAWDAR', ..., 'COCZFCR', 'COCZFCS']
```

For a pure recursive approach, try something like:

```
def num2words(s, i_s, i_chars, i_prev, prev, crnt):
    if i_s == len(s):
        return prev
    chars = mapping[int(s[i_s])]
    if i_chars == len(chars):
        return num2words(s, i_s+1, 0, 0, crnt, [])
    if i_prev == len(prev):
        return num2words(s, i_s, i_chars+1, 0, prev, crnt)
    char = chars[i_chars]
    crnt.append(prev[i_prev] + char)    
    return num2words(s, i_s, i_chars, i_prev+1, prev, crnt)
    
num2words("2", 0, 0, 0, [""], [])
# ['A', 'B', 'C']
num2words("26", 0, 0, 0, [""], [])
# ['AM', 'BM', 'CM', 'AN', 'BN', 'CN', 'AO', 'BO', 'CO']
```

- `i_s`: index of digit within the phone number `s`
- `i_chars`: index within the chars that `s[int(i_s)]` maps to
- `i_prev`: index within the list of words produced by the digits before `i_s`

The idea is:

1. append the current character `char = mapping[int(s[i_s])][i_chars]` to the word `prev[i_prev]`
2. append the result to `crnt`
3. move `i_prev` forward
4. if `prev` has been fully processed, move to the next char
5. if chars have been fully processed, `crnt` becomes the new `prev` and move on to the next digit in `s` with a new empty `crnt`
6. if digits in `s` have been fully processed, return `prev` (which is the last `crnt` we have filled)

Comment: but that is using iteration, i want to use structural  or accumulated recursion only

Comment: I added a purely recursive approach.

Comment: when i try using '2629327' i get maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object